# JavaScript/jQuery - Array list does not go across whole board

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm working with `A* Pathfinding`. I got it working however it doesn't work all the way. It works all the way until the last `4` columns to the right. Weird.

It works all the way until X is 10 or less. Which is weird because `Y`'s max is `10`. Maybe it's together? I don't know. But my  map is `15 columns` by `10 rows`. Here is an online example: http://mystikrpg.com/html5/

An interesting error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined`.

The `8` is the `Y` of where you clicked. If you click a the very first gray block on the right-side (since row 0 is walled off). Then that `8` would say `1`.

Here's the part where it lays out the nodes.

```
// Creates a Graph class used in the astar search algorithm.
function Graph(grid) {
    var nodes = [];

    var row, rowLength, len = grid.length;

            for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
             row = grid[x];
             nodes[x] = new Array(15);
                for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {
                   nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[y]); 
                }
            }

    this.input = grid;
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

However, you can download it offline and put it on localhost, if you'd like here http://mystikrpg.com/html5/Ethios.rar

Anyway... something else I found:

My `loadMap()` function returns an array of `11` elements.

And when `x_block` is `13` (clicking on `X` axis of map) for example, `graph.nodes[x_block][y_block]` returns undefined.

Here is my `loadMap()` function:

```
    function loadMap(map) {
        if (map == 1) {
            return [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
[1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1], 
[1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
[1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1], 
[1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
[1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
[1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
[1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
[1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]];
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it's 15 columns across and 10 rows down.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE NEW**

```
for (y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {

    row = grid[y];
    nodes[y] = new Array(15);

    for (x = 0; x <= 15; x++) {

        console.log("X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
        //console.log("Row: " + row[x]);
        nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `x` and `y` nomenclature the wrong way around.

The `x` axis should be the *second* dimension in your table, e.g. `nodes[y][x]`:

```
for (y = 0; y <= 10; x++) {
    row = grid[y];
    nodes[y] = [];
    for (x = 0; x <= 15; x++) {
        nodes[y][x] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[y]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I know about that. I tried it like this buy my game is stuck. The page never finishes loading and the console for Chrome never loads up. :\

Comment: @weka It loads for me on Chrome 18, but stops working (without an error) as soon as I click past the leftmost 10 columns.

Comment: Hm. Yeah, but that's the problem I am trying to solve. Why I won't work on the 5 right columns.

Comment: @weka - because you've got your `x` and `y` mixed up - not here specifically, but in other parts of the code!  e.g. `graph.nodes[x_block][y_block]`

Comment: I edited my answer with new format. It's still giving me the error. Cannot set 0 of undefined.

Comment: @weka no, you've still got `nodes[x][y]` the wrong way around.

Comment: Switching x and y in that nodes or using your example freezes. I am using Chrome 19. Ah well. It's okay. I'll just mark it answered and move on with my life :\